# jQuery progressbar with ajax request to json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui-progressbar

I need some help with an ajax request and the use of data in a jQuery progressbar.

**Here is the index.html**

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

**Here is the test.json**

```
{ "progressbar":12 }
```

**Here is the JavaScript code**

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({ dataType:"json",
        url: test.json, 
        success: <!-- dont know what to do here -->,
    });

    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: <!-- Dont know what to do here  -->  
    });
});
```

I am sorry, but I am not used to jQuery and json. I would be glad for a really good example!!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: value section is use to determine the amount of completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your success to update the progress bar

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({ dataType:"json",
        url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/quannt/d60905a978058de2312b/raw/2d4ab1df422dc19b7214d10ffd5e80795e2aa0a5/gistfile1.txt", 
            success: function(data){
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: data.progressbar
                });
            }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qy1ko5xf/)

Comment: Its me again, can you help me here, with a very similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397998/input-src-data-from-json