# input src data from json

Tags: jquery, json, input, src

I got a very similar question here:
[jQuery progressbar with ajax request to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382882/jquery-progressbar-with-ajax-request-to-json?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Can you help me here with a solution?

I try to get the path out of a *.json file and use it for an "input image field" with jquery.

**HTML**

```
<input id="pic_1" type="image" src="<!-- what to do here? -->" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({ dataType:"json",
        url: test.json, 
        success: <!-- what to do here? -->,
    });
});
```

**test.json**

```
{ "pic_1":"img/test.png" }
```

would be glad for similar solution, due to [jQuery progressbar with ajax request to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382882/jquery-progressbar-with-ajax-request-to-json?answertab=votes#tab-top) !

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use $.getJSON() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/